# How to cache js, img and CSS file with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-rest

I use Spring Boot 2 with Spring Security and Thymeleaf. I have a setup for MVC and REST.

I search a way to cache JavaScript, image and CSS files.

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {
    ...

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public class RestWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
           ...
    }


    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationEventPublisher(authenticationEventPublisher).userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/css/**", "/webjars/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/")
                    .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                    .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutHandler())
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").and().csrf().disable();
        }
    }

}
```

I created this class:

```java
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**", "/webjars/**", "/img/**") 
                .addResourceLocations("/js/", "/webjars/", "/img/") 
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS));
    }
}
```

Same result, browser downloads all files every time.

Under `src/main/resources` I have:

```
static  
    css  
    img  
    js  

templates
```

**Edit**:

Response header:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length:95821
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Fri, 26 Jan 2018 15:40:55 GMT
Expires:0
Last-Modified:Fri, 02 Jun 2017 12:55:44 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

**Edit 2**

I added in my `FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class:

```java
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/webjars/**", "/js/**", "/img/**");
}
```

Same result.

Ok to get it working for css, js who are in the resources

mvc config is changed to

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/js/**", "/webjars/**", "/resources/img/**") 
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/js/", "/webjars/", "/resources/img/") 
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS));
    }
```

seem like not need to modify FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter antMachers to add ressources...

Answer (score 0):

try to add below code in spring boot main class (@SpringBootApplication)

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter webConfigurer () {
      return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
          @Override
          public void addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
              registry.addResourceHandler("/static/js/**")
                      .addResourceLocations("/static/js/")
                      .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS));
              registry.addResourceHandler("/static/images/**")
              .addResourceLocations("/static/images/")
              .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS));
              registry.addResourceHandler("/static/css/**")
              .addResourceLocations("/static/css/")
              .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS));
          }
      };
}
```

the files are in below paths :
[image]

you can add if the cache is private or public or must be revalidated
setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS).cachePrivate().mustRevalidate())